# How Do Daleks Reproduce?

Tags: doctor-who

The Daleks are a race of robot individuals with subtly distinct personalities, and as such, they do not belong to a hive/collective mind. They are not biological and cannot be born, so how do they reproduce and how are new individuals introduced?

Comment: Is it just me, or does anyone else now hear a Dalek voice going "FOR-NI-CATE! FOR-NI-CATE!"

Comment: @KeithHWeston: It's just your dirty little mind that is about to develop a fetish for Daleks.

Comment: You'll be out of luck, the last time anyone released Dalek porn, whatshisname sued them into oblivion.

Comment: Rule 42 applies.

Comment: They are not robots. They are biological.

Comment: Well, when a daddy Dalek and a mommy Dalek really, really love each other......

Answer (score 25):

A Dalek is a metal armour encasing a Kaled mutant (a "Muto").  This is the one-eyed octopus-looking thing you see in many Doctor Who episodes where the Dalek's armour opens.  A Dalek itself will not reproduce, as once the Kaled mutant has bonded with the armour opening the armour generally results in death.

[image: A Dalek's armour opened]

Mutos are of descendants of those mutated by chemical weapons in a war between Kaleds and Thals, both residents of Skaro, so they must be able to reproduce in some form.  This isn't revealed (understandably, in a children's program) but given octopi are also able to reproduce the mental image I'm getting is something similar (apologies for anyone else with a vivid imagination).

Apart from that, Daleks are known to use cloning to reproduce (as seen with the new "Paradigm Daleks") and have also shown a propensity to try to mutate humans and create new Daleks with these mutations, as Kaleds originally were similar to humans in their physiology.  The army established by the Dalek Emperor before being destroyed by Rose was born of Daleks formed from mutated human DNA.

Comment: Somebody's gunning for the reversal badge ... Nice answer!

Comment: The question won't get to -5 now that you've edited it. :) (Had to go look up Reversal; that looks like a tricky one.)

Comment: Sorry for that :)

Comment: See also [Inside a Dalek](http://www.thedoctorwhosite.co.uk/dalek/inside/) on The Doctor Who Site for images over the years.

Answer (score 0):

By experimenting on other species, until they turn into Daleks. But normally, Davros creates them. He once said in Journey's End, he grew them from his own body, but other than that, and experimentation, no other way of reproduction is known

Comment: I got a faint memory, I think from Genesis of the Daleks, that there was a cloning room full of embryos. The Doctor had a chance to blow it up but refused, he thought that there was hope for the forthcoming race to one day develop empathy. I'm fairly sure that he said they could continue cloning.